# Disable swagger by hostname - Spring

Tags: java, spring-boot, swagger, production-environment

is there any possibility to set security on swagger resources in Spring application based on the requested hostname (dynamic IP). Now I am using `@Profile` annotation to disable swagger in production, but I want to use swagger for my production service. I can access this service from two hostnames. One is public, the other is internal and secured by a VPN. I want to see swagger UI on internal address but I need to reject access from the public. Any suggestion? Thanks.

Comment: Can you try to use basic auth for swagger ?

Comment: Basic auth is also variant, but I would be happier if I could reject all swagger resources by requested domain. Service is behind proxy, which do not handle internal addresses.